# Can I get the AngularUI datepicker to wait until a promise is fulfilled before showing or changing the month?

Tags: angular-ui

I want to fetch data about the current month and then use `beforeShowDay` to mark some days on the datepicker. However, I would like to do it asynchronously. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured it out. I start the promise in the `onChangeMonthYear` callback an after the promise has been fulfilled I store my data and call a refresh:

```
this.datePickerOptions = {
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) { 
        var input = this;

        dashboardResource.getCalendarData().then(function (data) {
            //store and/or do stuff with data;
        });
    },
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {  
        //use said data to customize each date
        return [true, className, title];
    }
}
```